# Wordpress - Post to a custom PHP File - ERROR 500

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, wordpress

we're using WordPress for our Website. I was asked to add a function to our newsletter subscription that automatically sends an E-Mail to a specific address that is depending on the selected value of the form. Working fine from code side and on my local host, but when implementing it into the live wordpress system i ran across an error. The Situation :

jQuery.AJAX script posts form data to a file "mail.php" in the wp-content folder. the AJAX success function then submits the original form (because the data also needs to be posted to a provider that manages our newsletter subscriptions). This worked fine on a non-wordpress local host.

After searching through javascript console and firebug i realized that after the script tries to post data to the email.php the server returns a 500 Error as if it didnt allow the post to this file.

I did not register the mail.php or the script in any way but added it to the html code behind the e-mail form. Did i miss something here?

Thanks!

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery( "#subscribeform" ).one( "submit", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var pFirstName = jQuery("#firstname").val();
        var pLastName = jQuery("#name").val();
        var pSalutation = jQuery("#salutation").val();
        var peMail = jQuery("#email").val();
        var pDOB = jQuery("#dob").val();
        var pMailTo = jQuery("#shop").val();

        var data = {
            firstname: pFirstName,
            name: pLastName,
            salutation: pSalutation,
            email: peMail,
            dob: pDOB,
            mailto: pMailTo
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/cms/mail.php",
            data: data,
            success: function(){
                jQuery('#subscribeform').attr('action', "theExternalProviderURL").submit();
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**mail.php**

```
<?php

include_once '/cms/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

if($_POST){
    $shopname = $_POST['mailto'];
    $salutation = $_POST['salutation'];
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $dateofbirth = $_POST['dob'];
    $recipient = $_POST['mailto'];

    switch ($recipient) {
        case "Value1":
            $recipient = "mail1@mail.com";
            break;
        case "Value2":
            $recipient = "mail2@mail.com";
            break;
        default:
            $recipient = "admin@mail.com";
    }

    $oMailer = new PHPMailer;
    $oMailer->CharSet = 'UTF-8'; 
    $oMailer->isSMTP();
    $oMailer->Host = 'mail.host.com';
    $oMailer->Username = 'xxx';
    $oMailer->Password = 'xxx';
    $oMailer->SMTPAuth = true;
    $oMailer->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $oMailer->Port = 587; 
    $oMailer->From = 'email@email.com';
    $oMailer->FromName = 'From Email';
    $oMailer->addAddress('adress@adress.com'); 
    $oMailer->isHTML( true );
    $oMailer->Subject = 'E-Mail Subject';
    $oMailer->Body = 'Text Text Text';
    $oMailer->AltBody = strip_tags( $oMailer->Body );
    $oMailer->SMTPDebug = 2;

    if ( !$oMailer->send() ) {

        echo "Error sending Mail: " . $oMailer->ErrorInfo;
        exit;

    }
    echo 'Successfully sent mail to ' . $recipient . ' Shop'; 

}

?>
```

Comment: we need to see your code to help

Comment: HTTP error 500 means "Internal Server Error". This means that the PHP page is reached correctly, but then it runs into a (PHP) error.

Comment: Hi Mario and thanks for your comment. The error does not appear on my localhost and i've had multiple checkers check the code saying there's no error in it (mail.php)

Comment: check `error_logs` of the running server

Comment: I just posted my code - the values have been edited for privacy reasons of course, but i tested the script and it works well on local host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned earlier, HTTP 500 comes from problem in your server/mail.php code. Moreover, there is a special hook to work with ajax requests in WP, see here: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

What you need is something like:

```
 var data = {data:yourdata, action: "yourajaxaction"};
 $.post(ajaxurl,{data: data});
```

and

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_yourajaxaction', 'your_action' );

function your_action() { 
   include "mail.php";
}
```

Comment: Great i can do something with that. Thanks for the hint :o)